# Make a bash script sleep for x minutes

Tags: bash

I need to make a bash script wait for a while, then resume running.

```
Shebang
./script
Wait 10m
./thing
```

Answer (score 2):

Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296863/difference-between-wait-and-sleep) use: `sleep 600`.  This command takes an argument in seconds.